# Does a multimap iterator also need the type of the sorting function?

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question to answer. Do I need the `bool(*)(char,char)` in my `typedef` below, or can I just use `multimap<char,char>::iterator` in order to use `mmIt` iterators with the map `mmap`? Thanks for the help!

Code snippet:

```
bool fncomp (char lhs, char rhs) {return lhs < rhs;}
typedef multimap<char,int,bool(*)(char,char)>::iterator mmIt;
multimap<char,int,bool(*)(char,char)> mmap(fncomp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `multimap<K,V,Comp>::iterator` is a typedef for something else that doesn't depend on the comparator type, you might be ok - but this is an implementation detail, and will definitely break if it's a genuinely nested type.

Just sidestep it:

```
typedef multimap<char,int,bool(*)(char,char)> mMap;
typedef mMap::iterator mmIt;
```

and avoid writing out the whole multimap parameter list everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion (and makes for more readable code). I was mostly just curious.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the node and iterator types could be templates depending only on the key and value, just typedef'd into the container ... very fragile to depend on it though.

Answer (score 0):

Although the iterator doesn't need the comparison function, an iterator for say a `std::map<char,int,std::less<char>>` generally is a completely different type than an iterator for say a `std::map<char,int,std::greater<char>>`, because the iterator type is defined inside the specific map type and therefore on it.

A `std::map<K,T>` is actually a shortcut for `std::map<K,T,std::less<K>,std::allocator<std::pair<const K,T>>>`. So if the comparator of your map is different from the default one (which is `std::less<char>` in your case), then you need to explicitly instantiate the map type with it whenever you use it.

Comment: "because the iterator type is defined inside and therefore depends on the map" -- not necessarily true. They can also be a typedef for something outside the class.

Comment: @Xeo Well, it could be a typedef, but it needn't. And even then the type is still the inner typedef and not the actual outer type. I don't think the standard makes a difference between an actual dependent iterator type and a mere typedef. They're all just types depending on the concrete map type. A typedef conceptually is a type and not just an alias, no matter if two types happen to be the same *in a certain implementation*.

Comment: @Christian Thanks. Yes, I realized after posting the code that I should have done something more interesting with fncomp, since in this case it's the default behavior.

Comment: @Christian: "A typedef conceptually is a type and not just an alias" -- no, a typedef is *exactly* that. It's just another name *for the same type*. http://ideone.com/eZgI9

Comment: @Xeo I know that this works. What I meant was that the standard doesn't have this notion with regard to iterators. There is always a `std::map<...>::iterator` for each map type. That's all you can know, everything else is implementation defined. You never assume some typedef to always evaluate to a certain type, even if you know it's a typedef. Otherwise the typedef was just useless. So conceptually it's its own type and you mix different typedefs at your own risk. `vector::size` returns a `vector::size_type` and not an `unsigned int` for a reason.

Comment: @Christian: That's not how it sounded like in your other comment. Anyways, as I said in my answer, the standard *allows* it, but doesn't *guarantee* it - basically what you just said.

Comment: @Xeo Ok, I thought the word "*conceptually*" respresented the movement from the physical world into the world of ideas well enough. Wasn't the case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The standard *allows* your code to be correct, but it doesn't *guarantee* it.

Visual Studio 11 for example has so-called [SCARY iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2980.pdf) that don't depend on unnecessary types of the container (allocator, predicate). However, if iterators are implemented like that is completely implementation defined.

Comment: I was afraid that was true, and mostly just curious. Thanks.